# How can I verify hibernate.jdbc.batch_size is working?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In my hibernate properties I have 
 <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>

In my code I do something similar to

```
final StatelessSession sSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
try {
    sSession.connection().setAutoCommit(false);
} catch (final SQLException se) {
    // log a message
}
final Transaction tx = sSession.beginTransaction();
try{
    for ( some loop ) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
        sSession.insert(customer);
        /* Do we need to flush a stateless session? It doesn't have methods for it
        if ( i % 30 == 0 ) { //30, same as the JDBC batch size
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            sSession.flush();
            sSession.clear();
        }
        */
    } 
    //sSession.flush();// Do we need to flush a stateless session? It doesn't have methods for it
    //sSession.clear();
} finally{
    tx.commit();
    sSession.close();
}
```

My Pojo has the following

```
@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;
```

However, When I change the batch size it doesn't seem to affect the overall run time.  How can I verify that it is in fact working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment out `session.flush();` and see if anything is inserted after 20 loop interations

Update: to the updated question

commenting `//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` should fall back to default which is AFAIK Identity

try  using

```
@TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN", table="SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue="EMP_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
```

Comment: ok then batching doesnt work. a common scenario is if you use "identity" or "native" id generator then Hibernate must go to the db immediatly on save() to get the id.

Comment: Correct, I do not have an identity set.  See the updated code in the main post.

Comment: I should note that I'm currently manually setting the ids, so no 'strategy' should be needed.  I don't know if this affects disabling batching or not

Comment: After setting this I 'think' the batching is starting to take effect.  I see horrible run times for 30, but the same runtime as without batching for 300 and for 3000.  By any chance would you know how to determine what's the best batch number to use without randomly testing tons of them? Thanks!

Comment: i usually take 100, 300 or 1000, but best way is to profile it

Answer (score 1):

You can set hibernate.generate_statistics=true and look for stats on JDBC batches.