# Setting Hibernate property hibernate.jdbc.batch_size over explicitly calling session.flush()

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

Going through the batch processing document of hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html. I tried an example setting the batch size property(**hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20**) in hibernate configuration file and then doing flush and clear like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Now the thing is if I set the value of i to 50, then it flushes the records as a batch of 50. So, if I can control the batch size here in the loop , why do I need to set **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20** property.

Can someone please explain the difference between the two approaches i.e setting the property over calling flush explicitly.

Comment: Is your ID field in `Customer`  `IDENTITY` or manually set ?

Comment: I am using GenerationType.TABLE . So a sequence table is maintained for this.

Comment: check the comments on the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925940/how-can-i-verify-hibernate-jdbc-batch-size-is-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that your loop and `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` operate on different levels.

Your loop operates on entities (of your choice). But a single Customer might need multiple inserts (for example, when a Customer has multiple Adresses).
All these inserts get executed as simple single inserts with your loop approach. The `flush` and `clear` just prevent the session to grow without limit.

`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` on the other hand will bundle (insert)statements that are identical and only differ in in the parameter values into a single statement, with a list of parameter sets. The execution of such a batched statement should be processed much more efficient by the database then the equivalent single statements.

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is that, hibernate.jdbc.batch_size will bundle up 20 inserts in a single query, if the property is set to 20. And flush here, serves a totally different purpose here

Comment: Makes sense, Could be one of the reason that in the example also they have same value for i and the property, set to 20. So once the query is bundled up. We should flush it out to the DB.

Comment: It won't bundle them in a single SQL query. It will bundle the N queries into a batch, and finally execute the batch using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29. This limits the number of roundtrips to the database.